# Manhattan distance in R

Tags: r

I am going to calculate manhattan distance in R but I have a problem how to check if there exist a key in the hash.

My code is as follow. The error I am getting is in line with `if` statement.

```
library("hash")

h <- hash( list( Tom=list( Film1=4.0, Film2=1.0, Film3=4.0, Film4=4.0, Film5=1.0 ), Jon=list( Film1=3.0, Film2=5.0, Film3=4.0, Film4=2.5, Film5=3.0 ) ) )

manhattan_dist <- function(rating1, rating2){
distance <- 0

for(key in rating1){
  if( has.key( key, rating2 ))
    distance <- distance + (abs(rating1[[1]] - rating2[[1]]))
}
return(distance)
}

dist <- manhattan_dist(h$Tom, h$Jon)
dist
```

And the error is:

*Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘has.key’ for signature ‘"numeric", "list"’*

Comment: `h$Tom` is a `list` object, you are not operating with `hash` objects anymore. So `has.key` won't work. `for(key in names(rating1)) if( is.element( key, names(rating2))) distance <- distance + (abs(rating1[[1]] - rating2[[1]]))` would, for example.

Comment: @lukeA thank you for your response, this error is solved, thx but I am still getting wrong result - 0 and it should be 4, could you take a look and check where the problem is.

Comment: Have you found answer to your question. If yes, please answer your own question. Thanks

Comment: the manhattan distance is implemented by default, just used the `dist` function with `method="manhattan"` `?dist`

Answer (score 2):

should work like this if you pass vector

```
manhattan_dist <- function(rating1, rating2){
     distance <- abs(rating1-rating2)
     distance <- sum(distance)
     return(distance)
}
```